# Ruby Unit Tests fail in Eclipse on OS X

Tags: ruby, eclipse, macos, homebrew

I'm finally getting around to learning Ruby using Programming Ruby 1.9.  I have installed Ruby using Brew on OS X and it installed Ruby 2.0.

Most of the exercises have worked fine in Eclipse, but when I got to the first example that creates a unit test I started running into trouble.

In Eclipse, I created a test case like:

```
  require_relative 'WordsFromString'
  require 'minitest/autorun'

  class TestWordsFromString < Test::Unit::TestCase
    ...
  end
```

When I run it as a Ruby Test, I get the following output:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/ui/console/testrunner (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1276/0/.cp/testing/dltk-testunit-runner.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I think there might be something wrong with my basic Ruby installation because if I try and run it from the command line I get:

```
Asok:work_freq jeff$ ruby TestWordsFromString.rb 
TestWordsFromString.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Test (NameError)
```

EDIT:  With the help of Ursus I have figured out that as long as the require and base class are consistent the command line works.

So either of the following allow the command-line to successfully execute the test case.

```
  require 'minitest/autorun'    
  class TestWordsFromString < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
```

or

```
  require 'test/unit'
  class TestWordsFromString < Test::Unit::TestCase
```

So now I just need to get this working inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
class TestWordsFromString < Minitest::Test
```

Comment: That at least gets me part of the way there - it fixes the command line.  So now only Eclipse is failing.

Answer (score 0):

In searching around for a answer, I came across this [Ruby issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6875#note-9)
that seems to be relevant. Since I'm new to Ruby I'm not sure I fully understood it, but what I got out of it was that there was an unexpected behavior related to installing the gem *test-unit* that existed in Ruby 1.9. I hadn't installed any gems, so I tried:

```
gem install test-unit
```

after which the unit test executed successfully in Eclipse and on the command-line.